# unknown field `healthcheck` with Vector

Tags: logging, observability

I am trying to expose the endpoint "http://localhost:8686/health" using [Vector](https://vector.dev/) so that I can monitor the Vector's health.

After research, I came across guides that recommend putting the following code at the beginning of the `/etc/vector/vector.toml` configuration file:

```
[healthcheck]
enabled = true
```

However, when I validate the configuration file, it fails with the following:

```
x unknown field `healthcheck`
```

I don't know what is wrong or if this is the right way to monitor Vector's health.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To expose an endpoint, such as `http://localhost:8686/health`, you have to add the following lines at the beginning of the config file:

```
[api]
  enabled = true
  address = "0.0.0.0:8686"
```

Restart Vector and test the endpoint again.